# Window width and animation changing on the fly

Tags: jquery, animation, window, width

I'm trying to do a script which changes animation if using ie and browser window width is below 1400. my code(animation change) isn't working, althought console displays correct text when changing window width. Can anyone help?

here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



  function checkWindow() {


                if ( $.browser.msie ) {

                if ( $(window).width() >= 1400 ) {    

                $("#box1").everyTime(2, function(){                        
                         $("#box1").animate({top:"-20px"}, 3000).animate({top:"-10px"}, 3000);
                      });  
                $("#box2").everyTime(10, function(){                        
                         $("#box2").animate({top:"-100px"}, 2500).animate({top:"-90px"}, 2500);    
                      });        

                console.log("width over 1400");

                } else {

                $("#box1").everyTime(2, function(){                        
                         $("#box1").animate({top:"-200px"}, 3000).animate({top:"-100px"}, 3000);
                      });  
                $("#box2").everyTime(10, function(){                        
                         $("#box2").animate({top:"-200px"}, 2500).animate({top:"-900px"}, 2500);    
                      });    

                console.log("width under 1200");      

                }

                }

   }

var resizeTimer;


$(window).resize(function() {
     clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
     resizeTimer = setTimeout(checkWindow, 100);
});





});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps need a call to $.stopTime in there somewhere? Otherwise the $.everyTime calls are going to persist after the window is resized.